# is it possible to disable other checkboxes when setimeout if specific checkbox checked in apex-repeat?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

i have a program that can update multiple value, i wanted to give settimeout 2 second after click on spesific checkbox. when settimeout is loading the other checkbox in apex-repeat is disabled and when the settimeout is over the other checkbox will be enable again.

i tried so many ways and still not figure it out.
is it possible?

this is my code now:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!dataSalesPlan}" var="i">
<apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="checkOpex{!i.spd.ID} checkOpex {!i.spd.ID}" value="
{!i.opex}">
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!updateOpex}" reRender=""> 
   <apex:param name="salesPlanIndex" value="{!i.index}" assignTo="{!salesPlanIndex}"/>
   </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:repeat>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--screen-width', (screen.width - 120)+'px');
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    
    j$(document).ready(function() {
        j$(document).on('change', '.checkOpex', function(e) {
            var self = $(this);
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).removeAttr('disabled');
            alert("Succesfully Set Data");
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
```

Apex Code:

```
public List<Sales_Plan_Detail__c> getDataSalesPlan {get;set;}
public List<SPDWrapper> dataSalesPlan {get;set;}
public Id[] updateSPDIds {get;set;}
public Map<Id, Boolean> updateOpexList {get;set;}
public Integer salesPlanIndex {get; set;}

public void updateOpex() {
    SPDWrapper spdWrapper = dataSalesPlan[salesPlanIndex];
    if(spdWrapper != null){
        updateOpexList.put(spdWrapper.spd.Id, spdWrapper.opex);
        if(!updateSPDIds.contains(spdWrapper.spd.Id))
            updateSPDIds.add(spdWrapper.spd.Id); 
            if(spdWrapper.simulationSalesPrice < 100000000) {
                updateOpexList.put(spdWrapper.spd.Id, false); 
            } 
    }
}
```

Ilustrasi
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `apex:actionSupport`. That means that the changes you're making in JavaScript is being overwritten by the Visualforce runtime. You shouldn't mix server-side and client-side HTML updates simultaneously. I don't know what you're doing in updateOpex, but you should move it to the client-side code if possible, delay the server-side update until after the `setTimeout` fires, or use `apex:actionSupport` `oncomplete` to disable the checkboxes again.

Comment: I already update my question to show updateOpex code.
can i show alert and set disable button from server side? if u dont mind could you give me some example, thankyou so much for your help